# SSIS 2008 Excel Destination Connection error - 0x80040E37

Tags: oracle, ssis, database-connection, bids

I have an SSIS package (created in BIDS 2008). The package has a data flow task. Inside the data flow task I have an ADO NET Source and an Excel Destination.

I am connectiong to an Oracle DB, running a query, and then droping the results into an excel file on a different server. In order to connect to the Oracle DB I needed to create a system DSN for my connection. For the excel connection I am using the "table or view" drop down option and create a create table query that grabs the ouput from my sql query in the ADO NET connection.

Now if I drop the excel file on my local drive it works fine. But the end goal is to have this package drop onto a different server. So when I change the location on the excel connection to a different server (which I have access to) it doesnt work. When I open up the excel task and hit preview I get the following error-

### TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio

Error at Data Flow Task [Excel Destination [16]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E37.

Error at Data Flow Task [Excel Destination [16]]: Opening a rowset for "Excel_Destination" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Exception from HRESULT: 0xC02020E8 (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

I cannot find any resolutions for this problem. Now the ADO NET connection still works and if I hit preview on the query for the ADO NET source task I still get the desired data.

Would I need to add the DSN name to the server where I am dropping the excel file? Or is it better to drop the file on the local machine and then ftp the file to the other server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you populate the data in excel file in local drive in local machine or remote drive  via mapped drive to the server. the excel file with referencing sheet named "Excel_Destination" should exists on that location for SSIS package to write the data into that file.

The approach to write the file on the local drive then distribute it through ftp or batch script which copy this file looks OK in your case. You can write two package one writing excel file on the local drive and another one package which push or pull the file from/to local drive which can be scheduled.

Comment: Okay. Is this due to the progess for SIS creating an excel file? As when I drop a text file I had no issues dropping it on the other server.

Comment: No it's not, populating data in existing empty excel file with referring sheet named "Excel_Destination" should be working in similar way.

Comment: I found the problem. Although it shows the "Excel_Destination table/view" as the selection I need to re-create the table when I open the Excel Task. Once I do that it works properly. Thanks for your help.